# How to match strings split by "|e|" sign

Tags: java, regex, string

I've written a program to split a string by  `|o|`  and `|e|` signs.

This is my whole string (which I want to process):

```
code|e|0.07610 |o| p|e|0.02225 |o| li|e|0.02032 |o| applet|e|0.01305 |o| pre|e|0.01289
```

I write a utility function to parse the above string, The following is a part of this utility function :

```
String [] trs = tgs[1].split("[^ |o| ]"); //tgs[1] have the whole string
for (int i=0 ; i<9; i++) {
    String t = trs[i].split("[^|e|]")[0];
    e.add(new ProbTranslate(t, Double.parseDouble(trs[i].split("[^|e|]")[1])));
}
```

But it seems to be incorrect (cause I debug the program and then i get incorrect results). I feel that my mistake is in incorrect regex part. So I seek a proper regex for parsing the above string.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `.split("\\|[oe]\\|")`

Comment: *I feel that my mistake is in incorrect regex part* - that's right, the patterns are wrong as a negated character class still matches only one char other than those defined in the char class.

Comment: it seems that this is correct regex, but note that i one spaces around `|o|`, how can i insert these spaces to be matched ? @Tushar

Comment: You should read a tutorial on regular expressions, as you seem to misunderstand the meaning of `[]`: that is a character class, which matches a *single character*, not a sequence of characters.

Comment: There is another potential edge case when `|e|` and `|o|` are located one after another, and you want to split with them both. However, you actually can get rid of empty items in the array later.

Comment: You're right. The regex patterns are a complete and discrete world of programming and they are as large as a book! I must revise my lessons in regex. Anyway thank you. @AndyTurner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote special characters in regular expressions, Java provides a method: `java.util.regex.Pattern#quote`

Applying to your example above, this could e.g. lead to

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String[] split1 = "code|e|0.07610 |o| p|e|0.02225 |o| li|e|0.02032 |o| applet|e|0.01305 |o| pre|e|0.01289".split(Pattern.quote(" |o| "));

        for (int i = 0; i < split1.length; ++i) {
            final String name = split1[i];
            final String[] split2 = name.split(Pattern.quote("|e|"));

            for (int j = 0; j < split2.length; ++j) {
                System.out.println(split2[j]);
            }

            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
code
0.07610

p
0.02225

li
0.02032

applet
0.01305

pre
0.01289
```

Comment: Thank you. A different solution :) I keep using this sol.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Make two changes:

1. `"[^ |o| ]"` ➔ `"( \\|o\\| )"`
2. `"[^|e|]"` ➔ `"(\\|e\\|)"`

With those changes, your code would look like this:

```
String [] trs = tgs[1].split("( \\|o\\| )");
for (int i=0 ; i<9; i++) {
    String t = trs[i].split("(\\|e\\|)")[0];
    e.add(new ProbTranslate(t, Double.parseDouble(trs[i].split("(\\|e\\|)")[1])));
}
```

---

## Explanation

There are three problems with your regex.

1. `String#split(String)` splits around the subsequences that *match* the given regex.  Therefore, if you want to split around / remove every `|o|`, then your regex needs to match `|o|`.  However, it appears that you think (incorrectly) that the regex should match everything *other* than the split subsequence, since you are using a negated character class.  Don't do that.
2. In order to match (or exclude, for that matter) a complete substring in regex, the substring must be contained in parentheses, e.g. `(substring)`.  Parentheses denote a [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).  If you use brackets (e.g. `[characters]`), then it is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), which is equivalent to saying "any of these individual characters" rather than "this complete substring".
3. The character `|` is a control character in regex.  That means that if you want to match a literal `|` rather than using it to denote regex [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), then you must escape it.  And since this is Java, you must escape the `\` too so that Java doesn't try to change `\|` to some special Java character before the string even gets to the regex engine.  Hence, `\\|`.